# Verb (reach) + Preposition (to)

Tags: verbs, prepositions

Which is the correct usage?

1. He is reaching the mountains.
2. He is reaching to the mountains.

We usually say, he is driving to reach the mountains. I am just wondering, if "reaching to" is also correct in my above sentence.

Answer (score 2):

These 3 sentences mean 3 different things.  None mean the same.

> He is reaching the mountains

means he's arriving at the mountains now.

> He is reaching to the mountains

means he is extending his arm out to grasp the mountains.  Must have big hands and long arms.  Or small mountains.

What you 'usually say'

> He is driving to reach the mountains

means he's on his way but hasn't yet reached the mountains.

So your usage is only correct if you meant to say something different than you 'usually say'.

Comment: Your first interpretation has made me little confused. If "he is reaching the mountains" means that he has arrived in the mountains, then what is the difference between "he is reaching the mountains" and "he has reached to the mountains"? Do we also say "he has reached the mountains"?

Comment: @vinnieflores9000: you've not understood that "reach" has two completely different meanings, ably explained in the above answer. The meaning in your first sentence is "arrive", while the meaning in the second sentence is "stretch out" or "extend". Your comment also confuses past and present: we say "he is reaching" if he's now in the process of arriving, but we use "he has reached" if he arrived some time in the past.

Comment: To be a bit more specific, the second usage can either mean "stretch out", as in "he is stretching out his arm in the direction of the mountains", or it can mean "extend", as in "his gigantic body is extending from here all the way to the mountains." :-)